# WCF Net.Tcp binding to a localhost address will pop up Windows Firewall dialog, why?

Tags: wcf, tcp, firewall

I have a WCF Self-Hosted service with Net.Tcp binding configured. This service only needs to listen to a localhost port, so my service configuration code is as below:

```
var endpointBaseAddressUri = new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://localhost:{0}/{1}", availableTcpPort, parentID));
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(RenderOperation), new Uri[] { endpointBaseAddressUri }))
{
        var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = MAXBUFFER;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = MAXBUFFER;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = MAXBUFFER;
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding, guid);

    host.Open();

    // Other logic goes here
}
```

The problem is that, when the service is started with Administrator account, everything goes well. However if I logged on to Windows and start this WCF service with a regular account, following Windows Firewall dialog appears:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Since localhost is a loopback address, why Windows Firewall dialog still appears asking permission on a loopback address?
2. Is this the Windows Firewall setting related to the Net.TCP Listener Adapter? What is the best practice of Windows Firewall settings to get rid of this dialog?
3. Is there any workaround to not allowing the dialog to appear when a regular user is starting the WCF service?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you change localhost to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Will this make a significant difference? I cannot verify this at the moment because to be honest the problem appears in my customer's production environment. :)

Comment: Specifying **localhost** as an endpoint biding address just allows you to omit specifying **real** host name, so the current one can be used for service consuming. But your service still tries to listen the real TCP port, that's why the firewall asks you for permission. If you create a firewall rule, which would enable incoming requests for service port, this dialog will not appear anymore, and you will be able to call the service from IP addresses, which you specified in firewall rule.

Comment: Yes, I have resolved this issue by changing the localhost to 127.0.0.1. I know that adding the TCP port in the firewall rule would prevent the dialog from showing again. But in my scenario, the port number is dynamically generated and it is hard to add each generated port number into the firewall list. Thank you all for your help.